# Prove that $f(f^{-1}(T)) \subset T$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck solving this question. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a function and $T \subset B$, prove that 
$$f(f^{-1}(T)) \subset T$$

I think I need to prove that:

$$\forall t \in T: t \in f(f^{-1}(T))$$

which is equivalent with

$$\forall t \in T : t \in f(S) = \{ s \in S | f(s) \in T\}$$

with $S \subset A$

But I'm not sure if this even remotely correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting by drawing pictures is always helpful.

The idea is that for each $a\in A$, there is precisely one $b\in B$ such that $f(a) = b$, but given some $b'\in B$, there might not exist $a'$ such that $f(a') = b'$.

> I think I need to prove that
>   $$\forall t \in T: t \in f(f^{-1}(T))$$

This is not quite right, with this you end up trying to prove that $T \subset f(f^{-1}(T))$, which is false in general. Instead you need to show

$$\forall t \in f(f^{-1}(T)): t\in T$$

The proof is as follows:
Let $t \in f(f^{-1}(T))$. Then there must exist $a \in f^{-1}(T)$ such that $f(a) = t$. But then, because $a \in f^{-1}(T)$, $f(a)$ must be an element of $T$. Thus $t \in T$ as required.

**Addendum**

Let $S \subset A$. Try proving that
$$S \subset f^{-1}(f(S))$$

Comment: Reading your answer thoroughly helped me to grasp it. Thank you for your effort.